# Problem with two NSDate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, if-statement, io, nsdate

I have a problem with this code:

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
if (dateOne == today) {
dataLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; NSLog(@"inside if");}
NSLog(@"today:%@", oggi);
NSLog(@"dateOne:%@", dateOne);
```

the result of console is

```
2011-06-10 17:19:00.170 Project[678:707] today:2011-06-10 15:19:00 +0000
2011-06-10 17:19:00.174 Project[678:707] dateOne:2011-06-10 15:19:00 +0000
```

I also try "isEqualToDate" but the code don't entry inside "if"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I understand you are trying to determine if a given `NSDate` is today. To do this you don't have to take in consideration hours, minutes, etc. in your comparison. How about this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *today = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:otherDate];
NSDate *dateOne = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

if([today isEqualToDate:dateOne]) {
    ...
}
```

The method `isEqualToDate:` won't do *this* job because it checks whether a given date is exactly equal the receiver (with sub-second precision).

The `==` operator is not appropriate for this either because it compares the pointers to the objects, it checks whether the pointers point to the same memory location.

Comment: This answer is extremely useful for me. Thanks is small to give you.

Answer (score 0):

`==` compares pointers to see if they point to the same object -- not the values of the object themselves. To compare dates, use `-[NSDate isEqualToDate:]`:

```
if ([dateOne isEqualToDate:today]) {
    dataLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    NSLog(@"inside if");
}
```